# Rails - No "Mate" command for .gitignore - Using InstantRails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, command-line

Hey guys, This is my first time making an app with any kind of version control and the idea of it sounds awesome.  I'm just getting started and using some tutorials to figure it out.

I created my app....

```
rails example
```

Then started up git.....

```
git init
```

and now I'd like to make an .gitignore file which most tutorials are using

```
mate .gitinit
```

Sadly I don't have TextMate, though I see how it is completely awesome...So I'm asking what would be the command to create the .gitignore file within instantrails, which is the environment I've been using?  I'm not too experienced with playing around with all this command line stuff.

So yes, my question is how can I make a .gitignore file if I don't have the mate command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mate command just opens up TextMate, opening or creating the named file. You can create a .gitignore file using any text editor. Use whatever you normally use for creating and editing text files.

Comment: Should you I just add the file into the root of my apps directory?

Comment: Add it to the top of the source tree (the directory where you are calling `git` from).

Answer (score 2):

If you only have a couple patterns that you want in your .gitignore file, you can create one very quickly from the command line by typing `echo pattern1 > .gitignore` for some pattern pattern 1. You can add a second line with `echo pattern2 >> .gitignore`.  Use ">" to create a new file or overwrite an existing one, and ">>" to add to a file.

Of course, this can get tedious if you have a lot of patterns you want to add, but for short .gitignore files, it's faster than using a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, this blog posting give a great concise example of using gitignore.

http://www.gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html